# Test initial checked state of checkbox

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a (simplified) component:

```
function Checkbox(initialState) {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.checked = initialState;
  }, [initialState]);


  return (
     <input ref={myRef} />
  );
}
```

I want to test in React Testing Library that the initial checked state of the checkbox equals the value of `initialState`

```
  it('has a checked state', () => {
    render(<Checkbox initialState={true} />);
    const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
    expect(checkbox.getAttribute('checked')).toBe(true);
  });
```

The test fails because `checkbox` has a `checked` attribute of null, not true.

Comment: Why are you using a ref for this? Also note you're not handling the props correctly, please give a [mre] that actually recreates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `checked`property(js property) instead of attribute(declaration in initial HTML markup... If it was static HTML)

```
it('has a checked state', () => {
    render(<Checkbox initialState={true} />);
    const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
    expect(checkbox.checked).toBe(true);
  });
```

PS I'd also suggest you to use [`defaultChecked`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) prop instead of using imperative set through `.current.checked = true`

Comment: many thanks for pointing out the defaultChecked prop!